# Escaping JavaScript String

Tags: javascript

I am using `$.ajax()` to make a web service call from my client script. The data for this call is defined as follows.

```
data: "{ term: '" + request.term + "' }",
```

The problem is that `request.term` contains what the user typed into a text box. So what happens if it contains quotes or other unexpected characters?

Is there a function to escape any such characters so that the resulting JSON string will be correctly formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't build JSON by hand.

Don't manually escape data for JSON.

Use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var obj = {
    term: request.term
};
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
// etc
data: json,
```

- [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3)
- [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Even if I follow this advice, my actual code contains additional text that must be combined with the text entered by the user. How can I form such a string without invalid characters?

Comment: @JonathanWood — That's what JSON.stringify does.

Comment: @JonathanWood — If, by "multiple data items", you mean "objects with more than one property" then it works in the same way as an object with a single property. A JavaScript data structure goes in and a string of JSON comes out.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still missing something. If my string would've been `term: ' + request.term + ', arg2: ' + blah2 + ', arg3: ' + blah3`. How do I safely pass that to `JSON.stringify()` or anything else.

Comment: You don't build the JSON string by hand.

Comment: `var obj = {
    term: request.term, arg2: blah2, arg3: blah3
}; var json = JSON.stringify(obj);`